# Regex with three or more 7 and only small letters

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I need to write a Regex that matches string that:

-can't have letters k/l/m

-must have three or more digit 7

-can't have any big letters

-can't have a space sign

I wrote `"(?=.*7.*{3,})[^A-Zklm ]*"`, but I have some kind of feeling that this is not right, perhaphs I'm not seeing some obvious case where this is not gonna work, can anyone confirm?

Comment: Big letters of what languages?  A-Z or also ÄÖÜ etc.?

Comment: What's the application of such a regex - or is it just homework?

Comment: Can you provide some valid and invalid examples in your question?

Comment: You don't need a lookahead to do that, but groups and anchors (or implicit anchors).

Comment: Can it contain any other whitespace character than space? \t \n \r ?

Comment: Your regex is wrong, OP.  I suggest just writing it without using lookaheads or groups.  This will force you to repeat `[^A-Zklm ]` a couple times, but the answer is ultimately very simplle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(?=(.*7.*){3,})[^A-Zklm ]*
```

You just needed that group around `(.*7.*)`.

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
^(?!.*[A-Zklm ])(.*7.*){3,}$
```